# Opening android app from calendar event

Tags: android, url, events, calendar

There is requirement in application such that, When user clicks a button, then an event will be automatically created in calendar. Now there should be some link\ text in description such that when user clicks that then application should open. If that application is not installed then the link should open in browser. Please don't redirect me to other stack overflow links. I have searched a lot but haven't find a suitable answer.

Comment: You should use BroadcastReceiver for Android Calendar events. This is the way such things work on Android OS.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. What is your question? If your question is "how do I do this?", please explain what you have tried and what specific problems you have encountered.

Comment: Hi michael, It would be really nice if you could explain with example

Comment: Hi commonsware, I tried using intent filter in my app but horribly failed. Do you have any workig example

Comment: "I tried using intent filter in my app but horribly failed" -- then open a Stack Overflow question where you provide your code and explain, completely and precisely, what "horribly failed" means.

Comment: CommonsWare ... either post some useful solution or stop commenting on post